# How to print more accurately 3D cube test?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ender3

I have print problems with my Creality Ender 3 S1 and I have calibrated all axes:

- Belts both X and Y axex
- Extremes of the X-axis horizontal structure have the same distance to the bottom of the printer
- Wheels both the X-axis and Y-axis (wheels under the bed) are correct

However, after I printed the cube the results weren't good enough. Print details:

- I have provided the [3mf file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hemOMdQCp5A_M_A5_028-5TrXdFdubzt?usp=sharing)
- PLA
- Ender 3 S1
- 0,24 mm (first layer 0,20 mm)
- Speed: perimeters 60 mm/s (external perimeters 50 %)
- Speed: solid infill 30 mm/s; top solid infill 15 mm/s

[image: Photo of the X side of a calibration cube]

[image: Photo of the Y side of a calibration cube]

[image: Photo of the Z side of a calibration cube]

Comment: Usually the first layer is bigger than the rest. How fast are you printing? It looks as if it is printed really fast.

Comment: @0scar I updated the post with data about print speed, however I answer your question below:
- Speed: perimeters 60mm/s (external perimeters 50%)
- Speed: solid infill 30mm/s; top solid infill 15mm/s